# How do I change the default arrangement of the attributes in the upgrade attributes option

Tags: magento

How do I change the default arrangement of the attributes in the upgrade attributes option on the main catalog page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: thank you. sorry, i'm a rookie in this game.